# php and javascript calculation in form process

Tags: javascript, php

I have one form process. I want to show total price

based on

1. Selection of product..
   price will appear automatically (dependent dropdown)
2. user input the quantity
3. so, Total price showing automatically (input quantity * dropdown price)

Kindly waiting for your code ideas.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far, we can help you fix it ... not here to build it for you.

Comment: This could easily be found with a simple google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page will be combination of PHP+Javascript+(Ajax optional) for functionality.
When page is loaded, create one `select box` having value as `product id` and label as `product name`. Also Keep the `product id` and `price` info as `javascript` map or within the dom as some elements. 
Whenever user select any product and enter quantity fetch the product price from `javascript` map and multiply with quantity to show as total price.

Note: if product prices are changed frequently, fetch the product price using ajax call to server.